# what are the events (ex MODEL_VERSION_CREATED) associated with ML FLow Databricks CI/CD

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, mlflow

ML Flow has multiple events to subscribe like MODEL_VERSION_CREATED when a model version is created. what are the other events available to subscribe.

Comment: are you asking about MLflow webhooks?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference model by 2 ways –

**Model_Version**

**Model_name**

You can get more information on Creating new Model Version from this [notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_static/notebooks/mlflow/mlflow-model-registry-example.html)

Comment: The question is about different functionality...